# DrawerLayout главная активность

Tags: xml, android, java, activity

Имеется DrawerLayout, в списке там несколько элементов, и по каждому клику открывается новая активность. Так вот при запуске должна запускаться основная активность, но запускается та, которая указана первой в списке.

Вот код:

```
private void selectItem(int position) {

    switch(position) {
    case 0:
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Two.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;  
    сase 1:
    Intent intent ...
```

В общем, при запуске программы открывается класс Two, в настройках программы все нормально, в манифесте все прописано, я же не могу сделать так, чтобы было

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
```

Вот часть манифеста. Я думал сначала, это мелочь, но в итоге что-то подвис на этом.

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы имеете в виду, что при запуске приложения у вас так получается:

1. Запуск MainActivity;
2. Выбирается 0 элемент в DrawerLayout;
3. По выбору 0 элемента вызывается класс Two (тоже Activity, надо полагать?);

а хочется, чтобы приложение понимало, что это первый запуск, то можно пометить первый запуск флагом. Например так:

1) Создаём переменную в классе MainActivity

```
private boolean firstLaunch=true;
```

2) В selectItem(int position) делаем проверку на первый запуск Активити. Если это он, то меняем значение флага, а активити не стартуем.

```
private void selectItem(int position) {

switch(position) {
case 0:
if(firstLaunch)
{
firstLaunch=false;
}
else
{    
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Two.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
break;  
сase 1:
Intent intent ...
```

Ну и не забываем сохранить значение firstLaunch переменной в onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)

```
onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
savedInstanceState.putBoolean("flag", firstLaunch);
}
```

и восстановить её в onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
...
if(savedInstanceState!=null)
{
this.firstLaunch=savedInstanceState.getBoolean("flag", false);
}
```